# Is it possible to register dependencies by convention in .NET Core?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

Some containers allow for registration by name. Ninject is one as an example.

Does the .NET Core DI container support this? And if not, are there plans or third party libraries to support this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does the .NET Core DI container support this? And if not, are there
>   plans or third party libraries to support this?

Short Answer: **NO** and **NO**

Source: [Introduction to Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#recommendations)

> **Replacing the default services container**
>
> The built-in services container **is meant to serve the basic needs of
>   the framework and most consumer applications built on it**. However,
>   developers can replace the built-in container with their preferred
>   container. The `ConfigureServices` method typically returns void, but if
>   its signature is changed to return `IServiceProvider`, a different
>   container can be configured and returned. There are many IOC
>   containers available for .NET.

(Emphasis mine)

With that you can check if Ninject has an extension for .net core and see if you can integrate it.

Comment: Technically you can, but you have to build your own extension methods to do it with a bit of Reflection.

Answer (score 10):

You can write your own convention, a simple example would look like this:

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Startup))
    .ExportedTypes
    .Where(t => t.IsClass)
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetInterfaces(), (c, i) => new {Class = c, Interface = i})
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => services.AddTransient(x.Interface, x.Class));
```

You can extend it to include abstract classes, non-public types, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> > And if not, are there plans or third party libraries to support this?

Try this https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.